# How to register a singleton in a child container?

Tags: structuremap

I am having trouble registering a singleton in a StructureMap child container.

The singleton has a dependecy which is registered in the same container.

When trying to resolve the singleton, it fails saying it cannot determine the dependency. Whereas I can resolve the depency manually without problem.

The following code snippet shows the issue:

```
[Test]
public void should_be_able_to_instantiate_root()
{
    var parentContainer = new Container();
    var childContainer = parentContainer.CreateChildContainer();

    childContainer.Configure(x =>
    {
        x.ForSingletonOf<IRoot>().Use<Root>();
        x.For<IDependency>().Use<Dependency>();
    });

    Console.WriteLine(childContainer.WhatDoIHave());

    var dependency = childContainer.GetInstance<IDependency>(); // Works

    var root = childContainer.GetInstance<IRoot>(); // Fails ("No default Instance is registered and cannot be automatically determined for type 'IDependency'")
}

public interface IRoot
{
}

public class Root : IRoot
{
    public Root(IDependency dependency)
    {
    }
}

public interface IDependency
{
}

public class Dependency : IDependency
{
}
```

`childContainer.GetInstance<IRoot>()` throws the following exception:

```
StructureMap.StructureMapConfigurationException : No default Instance is registered and cannot be automatically determined for type 'StructureMapIssue.IDependency'

There is no configuration specified for StructureMapIssue.IDependency

1.) new Root(*Default of IDependency*)
2.) StructureMapIssue.Root
3.) Instance of StructureMapIssue.IRoot (StructureMapIssue.Root)
4.) Container.GetInstance(StructureMapIssue.IRoot)
```

Here is the output from `childContainer.WhatDoIHave()`, you can see `IDependency` is there:

```
Profile is 'DEFAULT'

========================================================================================================
PluginType           Namespace             Lifecycle     Description                               Name     
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Func<TResult>        System                Transient     Open Generic Template for Func<>      (Default)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Func<T, TResult>     System                Transient     Open Generic Template for Func<,>     (Default)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IContainer           StructureMap          Transient     Object:  StructureMap.Container       (Default)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IDependency          StructureMapIssue     Transient     StructureMapIssue.Dependency          (Default)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IRoot                StructureMapIssue     Singleton     StructureMapIssue.Root                (Default)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Lazy<T>              System                Transient     Open Generic Template for Func<>      (Default)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root                 StructureMapIssue     Transient     StructureMapIssue.Root                (Default)
========================================================================================================
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't male much sense to register a singleton in a child container, considering that the default behaviour of something being instantiated in a child container is that the instance sticks around until the child container is disposed.

Additionally, a child container is not meant to stick around for a long time - at least not as long as the parent.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! It was an issue in StructureMap which has been fixed recently: https://github.com/structuremap/structuremap/issues/330